# Make 3 Responsive Columns?

Tags: css, sass

I want to make a responsive grid of columns just like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRgyK.png). That's what I want it to look like in desktop mode.

In the mobile mode, I want it to shrink and stack on top of each other when I resize the browser.

How do I do this?

Here's my code:

```css
.help-icons {
        height: 10rem;
        width: 10rem;
    }

    .icon-one,
    .icon-two,
    .icon-three,
    .icon-four,
    .icon-five,
    .icon-six {
        border: 1px solid $color-silver;
    }

    .dark-text {
        font-size: 0.7rem;
    }

    .light-text {
        color: $color-boulder;
        font-size: 0.5rem;
    }
```

```html
.help-icons
        .icon-one
            span.wfs-pie-chart
            p.dark-text Some Text
            p.light-text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        .icon-two
            span.wfs-user
            p.dark-text Some Text
            p.light-text Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque.
        .icon-three
            span.wfs-git-branch
            p.dark-text Some Text
            p.light-text Mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam.
        .icon-four
            span.wfs-database
            p.dark-text Some Text
            p.light-text Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum.
        .icon-five
            span.wfs-trending-up
            p.dark-text Some Text
            p.light-text Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in.
        .icon-six
            span.wfs-cloud
            p.dark-text Some Text
            p.light-text Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet.
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I have media queries for the mobile, tablet, and desktop already:

```
//- Mobile
@media screen and (min-width: 15rem){
}

// Tablet
@media (min-width: 768px) {
}

// Desktop
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
}
```

Comment: Use css mediaquery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ShibinRagh/21woux5p/6/  @coder

Comment: @ShibinRagh, yes, I have media queries already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this would be useful.

```css
.help-icons {
        width: 100%;
    }
.help-icons > div {
    width: 10rem;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

    .icon-one,
    .icon-two,
    .icon-three,
    .icon-four,
    .icon-five,
    .icon-six {
        border: 1px solid $color-silver;
    }

    .dark-text {
        font-size: 0.7rem;
    }

    .light-text {
        color: $color-boulder;
        font-size: 0.5rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class="help-icons">
              <div class="icon-one">
                <span class="wfs-pie-chart"></span>
                <p class="dark-text"> Some Text</p>
                <p class="light-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
              </div>
               <div class="icon-two">
                <span class="wfs-user"></span>
                <p class="dark-text"> Some Text</p>
                <p class="light-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon-three">
                <span class="wfs-git-branch"></span>
                <p class="dark-text"> Some Text</p>
                <p class="light-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon-four">
                <span class="wfs-database"></span>
                <p class="dark-text"> Some Text</p>
                <p class="light-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon-five">
                <span class="wfs-trending-up"></span>
                <p class="dark-text"> Some Text</p>
                <p class="light-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon-six">
                <span class="wfs-cloud"></span>
                <p class="dark-text"> Some Text</p>
                <p class="light-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
              </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @GauravRana! That's what I'm looking for. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Bootstrap's `row` and `column` classes. This way it is not necessary for any media queries as Bootstrap does it all for you. Just make sure you have Bootstrap installed in your project, then you can make use of the following code in your html:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="row">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="row">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="row">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You can check out Bootstrap's documentation for different screen size breakpoints: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/. You can also change the width and height of rows and columns to your liking, by targeting the Bootstrap classes or adding custom classes to the Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Thanks @Corné! I'll check it out soon. :)

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to ask if you have any further questions regarding this. Also, please remember to mark the answer that worked for you as `answered` for any future queries regarding this.

Comment: Thank you! :D  I'm testing this out now.